# Delete database rows that don't fit new criteria (in ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails application where a "profile" has a has_many association with another model, where the other model has one primary defining attribute that is selected via drop-down. I'm doing an update where the values in the drop-down are going to be changed and I want the underlying data in the database to reflect this change.

When I deploy to the server, what is an easy/clean way to delete any pre-existing database entries for items that no longer are included in the drop-down list (I have the drop-down list data accessible in an array)? Is there any way to do it in a migration (or would it even make sense if I'm not changing any actual database structure)?

I'm not overly familiar with rails, so I hope this is clear!

Answer (score 0):

The rails way in this instance is to just use plain sql in your migration file

```
execute <<-SQL
  delete from <table> where <field> not in .... 
SQL
```

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, that would be inside of "def up ... end" in a migration, with nothing else needed?

Comment: Yes.. in your def up()  or def change().  With legacy state, sometimes you can't avoid SQL in your migrations